# Composer can't update amphp/parallel-functions. dev-master is not recognized as a valid constraint

Tags: php

Error - Root composer.json requires amphp/parallel-functions dev-master, found amphp/parallel-functions[v0.1.0, v0.1.1, v0.1.2, v0.1.3, v1.0.0, v1.1.0, 1.x-dev, v2.0.0, 2.x-dev] but these do not match your constraint and are therefore not installable.

PHP version - 8.1.0

composer.json

```
{
require : {
"amphp/parallel-functions": "dev-master"
}
}
```

Trying to do composer update but it fails

Answer (score 0):

This project [doesn't have](https://github.com/amphp/parallel-functions/branches/all) the `master` branch. You may use `1.x-dev` or `2.x-dev` as suggested by composer.

The part before `-dev` is an actual branch name that must exist in the repository.